# Capitalizing the name of reference list in my function

Tags: python, function

I have bunch of lists, and I have a function to compare the reference list with all the other lists by their matching contents.

```
ABCC = ['TRIM29', 'IGL@', 'DOCK6', 'SVEP1', 'S100A11', 'EPHA2', 'KLHL7', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

ACC = ['GULP1', 'PREPL', 'FHL1', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BEC1 = ['LMNA', 'NHP2L1', 'IDS', 'ATP6V0B', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARN = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA']

lists = ([("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)])

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))
```

How can I capitalize the name of reference list through using `.upper()`.

`def sort_by_matches(ACC, lists)` should give same results as

```
def sort_by_matches(acc, lists)
```

I tried this, it did not work.

```
def matches(ref, lists):
    ref = ref[0].upper()
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("Gene Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

NameError: name 'acc' is not defined
```

Comment: `lists = ([("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `eval()`. But you have to pass the ref as a string e.g. Though its always better to use dictionary data structure.

```
lists = ([("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)])

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    ref = eval(ref.upper())
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        if matches != 0:
            print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

sort_by_matches('acc',lists)
```

Output:

```
Matches 53 in ACC
Matches 3 in BEC1
Matches 1 in ABCC
```

Variables are case sensitive.

Comment: No need to use `eval` if you pass a string: `[i[1] for i in lists if i[0] == ref.upper()][0]`

Comment: `ref` is a variable name

Comment: Yes but `i[1]` is a list. `lists` is a list of tuples ( name, var )

Comment: @Bharathshetty Thanks a lot, it solves the issue, but it makes the function harder to call. I want to simplify calling function.
No way to convert my variable to string like `str(ref)` ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty unrelated question:
how can I make the minimum number of Matches to show at 1?
So it does not print
`Matches 0 in ARN`

Comment: `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. But I must mention that I approve of your avatar. ;)

Comment: I was adding the dictionary method, but you  added it. So didn't put it here.

Comment: @Nguyen if you dont want `Matches 0 ` you can use a if statement

Comment: @Bharathshetty how to do it ?
I tried the
`lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True, min = 1)`

   `lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l)), min = 1), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)`

Neither worked.

Comment: @Nguyen if you want to remove matches  0 from the list itself then you can use `.pop()` . That will be lot simpler

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified version of your code that allows you to pass the list name as a string to `sort_by_matches`. To make it easy to access the lists we put them into a dict.

```
ABCC = ['TRIM29', 'IGL@', 'DOCK6', 'SVEP1', 'S100A11', 'EPHA2', 'KLHL7', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

ACC = ['GULP1', 'PREPL', 'FHL1', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BEC1 = ['LMNA', 'NHP2L1', 'IDS', 'ATP6V0B', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARN = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA']

lists = dict([("ABCC", ABCC), ("ACC", ACC), ("BEC1", BEC1), ("ARN", ARN)])

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(lists[ref.upper()])
    found = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists.items()], 
        key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, _ in found:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

# test

for ref in ('ABCC', 'acc', 'bEc1', 'Arn'):
    print(ref)
    sort_by_matches(ref, lists)
```

**output**

```
ABCC
Matches 43 in ABCC
Matches 1 in ACC
Matches 0 in ARN
Matches 0 in BEC1
acc
Matches 53 in ACC
Matches 3 in BEC1
Matches 1 in ABCC
Matches 0 in ARN
bEc1
Matches 47 in BEC1
Matches 3 in ACC
Matches 0 in ARN
Matches 0 in ABCC
Arn
Matches 9 in ARN
Matches 0 in ABCC
Matches 0 in BEC1
Matches 0 in ACC
```

---

We can make this a little more efficient by saving the lists into the `lists` dictionary as sets. I won't repeat those list definitions themselves here because they remain the same.

```
lists = dict([("ABCC", set(ABCC)), ("ACC", set(ACC)), ("BEC1", set(BEC1)), ("ARN", set(ARN))])

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = lists[ref.upper()]
    found = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(l)), name, l] for name, l in lists.items()], 
        key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, _ in found:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))
```

---

If you don't want the lines printed where the number of matches is zero, we just need an `if` statement:

```
for matches, name, _ in found:
    if matches:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))
```

Comment: I have hundreds of lists like ABCC, ACC.
Thanks for answer, but its not the shortest.

Comment: @Nguyen I just made some minimal changes to your code. If you have hundreds of lists you should have said so in the question. And if you have hundreds of lists you should _not_ be hard-coding them into lists with separate names, they belong in a collection.

Comment: @Nguyen I assume you are reading that list data from one or more files. If so, it should be straight-forward to construct a dictionary like the `lists` dictionary in my code. You certainly don't need to hard-code it like the `lists` in my little code snippet.

Comment: @Nguyen I've just add some more code, showing how to avoid printing lines with zero matches.

Answer (score 0):

In python the variable names are case sensitive.

If you define `ACC = ['some', 'list']` you can not then use `acc`.

Comment: Dear @Rahul
I want to convert any of my reference list into all CAP.
Such as if someone writes
`sort_by_matches(ACc, lists)` or
`sort_by_matches(aCC, lists)`

My function returns results for `sort_by_matches(ACC, lists)`

I want to edit the function to make reference list name all caps, not edit every one of my lists.

Comment: @Nguyen That's _possible_, but it's a **really** bad idea. As Rahul said, Python is a case-sensitive language. You can certainly make functions that can do case-insensitive searches for a string, but you shouldn't try to do the same sort of thing with identifiers (variable names).

Comment: @PM2Ring noted that its case-sensitive. That's why I want to convert it to all-caps, whenever reference name is written.

Comment: @Nguyen: Use VBscript. It's case insensitive.

Comment: Maybe you can do someting hacky with `clobals()` and `locals()` but i agree with PM2 Ring, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @Rahul I don't wanna complicate my code with VBscript.
Noted, its not a good idea to do this task on Python.

Comment: @Nguyen: It will be impossible in your case. You need to change your program structure structure before doing any hack.

Comment: @Nguyen So change your code so that people call the function with the _string_, not the variable name, eg, `sort_by_matches("ACc", lists)`.